# Android Why is my application not available on some compatible devices?

Tags: android, google-play, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, compatibility

I have recently launched my application into the Google Play store but unfortunately some users are unable to download the application due to market restrictions.
Users are able to install the apk directly without the market, so I guess it must be something to do with the manifest?

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

The application can be found here http://tinyurl.com/cnejnjs

Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.touchscreen
This application is available to over 185 devices.

For example one user has had trouble downloading it to his Galaxy Note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out having Copy Protection set to on within the application was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy Note runs Android 2.3.6, which is API Level 10. You are mandating at least API Level 11.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it was running a custom ICS rom.